# Bash: syntax error: unexpected end of file

Tags: bash, syntax-error

I have a script :

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ "$JAR_FILE" = "NewTekkit.jar" ]; then
cd "$SERVER_DIR"
unzip -nu "$JAR_DIR/NewTekkit.zip"
else
if [ "$JAR_FILE" = "TekkitLite.jar" ]; then
cd "$SERVER_DIR"
unzip -nu "$JAR_DIR/TekkitLite.zip"
fi
exit 0
```

And I get the error : `2013-05-31 18:00:44,817 DEBUG server 120: Server Prepare: Error: /home/minecraft/multicraft/scripts/startup.sh: line 11: syntax error: unexpected end of file`

Please help.

Thanks.

Comment: your first if is not closed

Answer (score 4):

You're missing a `fi`

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ "$JAR_FILE" = "NewTekkit.jar" ]; then
  cd "$SERVER_DIR"
  unzip -nu "$JAR_DIR/NewTekkit.zip"
else
  if [ "$JAR_FILE" = "TekkitLite.jar" ]; then
    cd "$SERVER_DIR"
    unzip -nu "$JAR_DIR/TekkitLite.zip"
  fi
fi
exit 0
```

properly indenting your code, also in shell, helps avoid this kind of issues.

Answer (score 3):

Your `if/else/fi` syntax is not complete (missing `fi`).

To detect such bugs prior to running your script you should always use

```
 bash -n scriptname
```

This performs a syntax check detecting such problems without actually running the script. You can also fix this with `elif` instead of an `else if` combination:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd "$SERVER_DIR"
if [ "$JAR_FILE" = "NewTekkit.jar" ]; then
  unzip -nu "$JAR_DIR/NewTekkit.zip"
elif [ "$JAR_FILE" = "TekkitLite.jar" ]; then
  unzip -nu "$JAR_DIR/TekkitLite.zip"
fi
exit 0
```

Using the shells string manipulation syntax it might even be possible to collapse the whole script to just

```
cd "$SERVER_DIR"
unzip -nu "$JAR_DIR/${JAR_FILE%jar}zip"
```

Ain't the shell a cool beast?